# tkinter dialog highlights parent entry text

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry, python-3.7

I am trying to duplicate the behavior of the Search Dialog of Python Idle, which highlights the text in the back. So I refer to this link and make my own dialog: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-dialog-windows.htm

[Python Idle Search Dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S0Rtr.png)

The problem is that with `self.grab_set()`, I am not able to highlight the text of parent window that calls the dialog. I don't want to remove the `self.grab_set()` because I also don't want users to click around when searching.

The onclick listeners of buttons are executed correctly as I have tested in other implementations of the dialog. For example, the text get replaced correctly using the replace dialog. So the only problem is the text of Entry in the parent window is not highlighted/selected. Actually, the text can be highlighted if I remove `self.grab_set()`. However, the dialog loses focus and the focus goes to the Entry of parent window once I do that. And I cannot press Enter to find next with the dialog.

How can I resolve this problem? Thanks in advance!

[My Implementation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCmUB.png)

---Update---

The testing code can be very simple like the following.

```
from tkinter import *

SYSTEM_HIGHLIGHT = 'SystemHighlight'
BUTTON_BORDER = '#b5b5b5'
class FindDialog(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Toplevel.__init__(self, master)
        self.master = master
        self.transient(master)
        self.grab_set()
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (master.winfo_rootx() + 50, master.winfo_rooty() + 50))
        self.title('Search Dialog')

        ## Variables
        self.findListner = None

        self.findLabel = Label(self, text = 'Find:')
        self.findEntry = Entry(self)
        self.findEntry.focus()
        self.findEntry.select_range(0, END)
        for i, w in enumerate([self.findLabel, self.findEntry]):
            w.grid(row = 0, column = i, sticky = NSEW)
        self.findEntry.grid(columnspan = 5)
        self.findButton = Button(self, text = 'Find Next', command = self.find)
        self.findButton.grid(row = 1, column = i + 1, sticky = NSEW)
        self.bind('<Return>', lambda event: self.find())

    def setOnFindListner(self, listener):
        '''listner should have the following arguments: dialog, target, direction.'''
        self.findListner = listener

    def find(self):
        if not self.findListner: return
        self.findListner(self, self.findEntry.get())

def find():
    dialog = FindDialog(root)
    dialog.setOnFindListner(onFind)
    root.wait_window(dialog)

def onFind(*args):
    e.focus_set()
    e.select_range(0, END)
    e.icursor(END)

root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.focus()
e.insert(0, 'HelloWorld')
root.bind('<Control-f>', lambda event: find())
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]. It's going to be hard for anyone to cobble together a working program from these snippets. When you create the [mcve], be sure to remove any functions that aren't necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sorry for being lazy. I have updated the question. The desired behavior of the testing code should be pressing find selects all the text of Entry e. However, it only selects it after the dialog is closed.

Comment: What are we supposed to do to see the problem? If I type control-f and then the letter "o" and then press enter, what should happen?  Also, we don't need to see so many blocks of code. Unless we're supposed to put all of that code into a single file, please just include the one complete example.

Comment: The desired behavior should be: I press the Find of dialog box, the entire text of Entry e should be selected without closing the dialog box. @BryanOakley

Comment: WIthout typing anything into the dialog box, it should select everything in the entry widget?

Comment: @BryanOakley For simplicity, yes. The real behavior should be like the search dialog of Python IDLE.

Comment: If your real problem is searching a text widget rather than an entry widget, that's an important detail that shouldn't be left out.

Comment: @BryanOakley No. I am searching an Entry widget. I thought these two would be similar. If this cannot be achieved using Entry I can switch to Text.

Answer (score 0):

Entry widgets are designed so that only one widget can have focus, and only the selection of the focused widget will be visible. Without this, it would be easy to create a UI where the user would have no way of knowing where keyboard events would go, or what a copy event would copy. This may not be true on all platforms, but it's been a while since I worked on anything other than a mac.

If your system allows multiple entry widgets to show a selection, you might be able to solve the problem by making sure the `exportselection` option is set to false for all of your entry widgets. If the widget your trying to highlight is a `Text` widget, that should be enough. It's not clear from your question if you're really needing to search a `Text` widget or an `Entry` widget, and that distinction is important.

Arguably the better solution is to use a text widget and your own custom tag rather than the selection, since your own tag won't have these limitations. You can make the tag look the same as the selection, or you can give it a different look so that it's clear that the highlighted code has a different behavior than code manually selected by the user.

Comment: What about text? I believe IDLE should be implemented with text. And it has 
text selection without focus.